# Signature of higher order functions in SML

Tags: sml, smlnj, higher-order-functions, operator-precedence

I have been trying to understand Higher Order Functions in SML. I know how to write simple higher order functions and also understand the signature. One example is:

```
fun increment list = map (fn x=> x + 1) list;
val it = fn: int list -> int list
```

However, I cannot understand the signature of the following higher order function:

```
fun add  x y = x + y;
val add = fn: int -> int -> int
```

The function could be written as:

```
fun add (x,y) = x+y;
val add: fn : (int * int) -> int
```

which I understand. But in the previous function, I fail to understand how the order of operations work. Does the function take two parameters at once, or does it take one at a time producing a new function which then produces the required result? How would it work for any other higher order function?

I need to build the concept about the signature of higher order functions for my homework as well as my exams coming up in a few weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SML, functions can be curried.

```
  - fun add x y = x + y
  val add = fn : int -> int -> int
```

is curried. This means that it can be partially applied, like this:

```
  - fun add2 x = add 2 x;
  val add2 = fn: int -> int
  - add2 3;
  val it = 5 : int
```

If we write the function as:

```
  - fun add2tuple(x,y) = x + y;
  val add2tuple = fn : (int * int) -> int
```

We are not actually passing in two parameters, but one tuple. That the tuple contains two integers is a description of the tuple's type.

- If we write the function in curried form, then the function parameters are not placed in a tuple.
- In the curried form, a function `fun f p1 p2 ... pn = ...` can be partially applied by passing between 1 and n-1 arguments.

But a function whose parameter is a single tuple cannot be partially applied.

```
- fun addordered x y = x + (2 * y);
val addordered = fn : int -> int -> int
- addordered 2 3;
val it = 8 : int
- fun addordered2 x = addordered x 2;
val addordered2 = fn : int -> int
- addordered2 3;
val it = 7 : int
```

This example might clarify that the tuple is a single thing:

```
- fun add3tuple(x,y,z) = x + y;
val add3tuple = fn : int * int * 'a -> int
- add3tuple(3,4,5);
val it = 7 : int
- add3tuple(3,4,"Hello World");
val it = 7 : int
```

Hope you enjoy Dan Grossman's class.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to keep in mind is that *all* SML functions take exactly one argument.  That argument may be a pair, as in your second `add` function, or an int, as in your first `add` function.  You are correct that the first `add` returns a function of type `int -> int`.  You could also have written

```
fun add1 x = fn y => x + y
```

which makes it more clear that it takes a single argument.  Or even

```
val add1 = fn x => fn y => x + y
```

(FWIW, your `double` function looks a bit odd.  It ignores its argument, and returns the same result every time.

```
fun increment list = map (fn x => x + 1) list
```

is probably what you meant.)

Comment: yes, so for example when you call `add 2`, you should think of this as getting back the function `(fn y => 2 + y)`, which is simply obtained by replacing all occurrences of `x` with the value `2`.